# How to include members with specific children in MDX query cross join?

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube, mondrian, olap4j

I'm new to MDX, and I have following scenario. I have to calculate revenue across specific department (product dimension), specific store (location dimension) and across specific time range.

I have my cube levels as follows. 
`Product <- Department <- Item` 
`Location <- Region <- Store` 
`Time <- Year <- Month <-Day`

Say if I have following members

```
[Product].[Dairy].[Oak Farm]
[Product].[Dairy].[GV]

[Location].[US West].[LA]
[Location].[US West].[CA]

[Time].[2015].[01].[01] : [Time].[2015].[02].[01]
```

Then I should get result as where in Product should include only GV and location should include only CA

```
2015-01-01        US West       Dairy       $100
2015-02-01        US West       Dairy       $100
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: people are voting to close your question because you have not provided an example of the mdx you have attempted.

Comment: did Sourav or myself help with our answer's - any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. What i was looking for is, Say there is a [Region1] with [Store1[], [Store2] and [Store3] as its child, say i have role Manager who authorised for [Store][Region1][Store1] and [Store][Region1][Store2] alone and when i need aggregation across [Region1], MDX should give me just aggregation over [Store1] and [Store2] alone instead of displaying it for all the 3 stores.

Comment: ok - easy enough I'll add an edit to my answer - you need a custom measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably several ways depending on exact requirements.

```
 SELECT 
   [Measures].[SomeCubeMeasure] ON 0,      
   {[Time].[2015].[01].[01] : [Time].[2015].[02].[01]}*
    Exists
    (
      [Location].[Region].MEMBERS
     ,[Location].[US West].[CA]
    )*
    Exists
    (
      [Product].[Department].MEMBERS
     ,[Product].[Dairy].[GV]
    ) ON 1
FROM [yourCube];
```

---

**Edit**

To create a measure that just looks at certain stores you could use something like this:

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Store1and2Measure] AS
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [Store][Region1][Store1]
       ,[Store][Region1][Store2]
      }
     ,[Measures].[SomeCubeMeasure]
    )       
 SELECT 
   [Measures].[Store1and2Measure] ON 0,      
   [Location].[US West].[LA] ON 1
FROM [yourCube];
```

Comment: I have exactly tried this. May be i should have posted question in different way. Actually what i need is the output should contain location at Region level which should contain only specific members of its children. Say if Region: [DFW South] includes Stores [Dallas], [Arlington], [Irving] but i need [Location].[DFW South] that should contain only [DFW South].[Dallas] and [DFW south].[Arlington] for the measures at region level

Comment: The edit is kind of useful. Only problem i have with this approach is say i need descendants of store dimension to be displayed in my table as well. In that case the above approach with give only the result from [Measures].[Store1and2Measure] across every descendants. Say i need <br/>
Region1                                          100
             Store1                                 40
             Store2                                 60
<br/>
but with above query it will display only 100 across every member.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way of doing it. @Whytheq gave a much better solution.

```
SELECT      
      (
       [Product].[Dairy].[GV]* 
       {[Time].[2015].[01].[01] : [Time].[2015].[02].[01]}*
       [Location].[US West].[CA]
      ) ON 1,
[Measures].Revenue ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: (upped) exactly that sort of stuff Sourav... imagine the reaction people would get from the community if a question was tagged `sql` and the answer was "SELECT X AS "X", Y AS "Y", SUMZ = SUM(Meas) FROM SOMETABLE GROUP BY X, Y" ...